# Upcoming Fork - Wallet Safety

Tags: wallet, development, bitcoin-core, address

In downloading the newer client, do I need to worry about my addresses and hence bitcoins disappearing, or will everything in the old wallet transfer nicely into the new?

Answer (score 3):

Everything should transfer just fine, but as with any change to your system you should take a backup of your wallet before upgrading, just in case.

Comment: You should always keep a backup of your wallet, just in case.